# TextInput slow on clear with a lot of content on screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, textinput

I have an issue that when I spam typing in a TextInput and click a button on to submit and clear the text it becomes laggy and it doesn't clear the text in the TextInput **right away**.
This happens when I have **a lot of content** within the Screen (like Lorem Ipsum text).

This is a problem for me, because I am developing a chat app and whenever the chat log is large and the users types and submits the message fast it won't get cleared immediately and will still remain in the TextInput, which is bad usability. I tried it with ref and controlled TextInput (no difference).

You can see the issue in my gif:

[image]

Here is a snack for expo to reproduce the issue:
https://snack.expo.io/s22hVf140

This is my code:

MyMessages:

```
const MyMessages = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const addMessage = (text) => {
    const arr = [text, ...messages];
    setMessages(arr);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <MyTextInput addMessage={addMessage}></MyTextInput>
      {messages.map((msg, i) => {
        return <Text key={i}>{msg}</Text>;
      })}
      <Text>
        Lorem ipsum.......
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

MyTextInput:

```
const MyTextInput = ({ addMessage }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const myRef = useRef();
  const submit = () => {
    myRef.current.clear();
    addMessage(text);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        ref={myRef}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: 50,
          backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
          marginTop: 50,
        }}
        onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
      ></TextInput>
      <Button title="submit" onPress={submit}></Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Anyone has an idea why this happens with large content on the screen?

Comment: Have you considered using a virtualized list like [`FlatList`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) to render each chat item in the log? This should provide some rendering performance boosts. You should also use some devtools to help determine what's causing the "more than expected" rendering load.

Comment: @98sean98 this issue also happens with a FlatList. I couldn't figure out how to use a profile dev tool properly, but this is really all my code (see the snack to reproduce it)

Comment: Do you have the same issue in production? Or only in dev mode?

Comment: I've checkout your snack code. At first I thought your rendering could be improved by taking into account [how react's dom diffing algorithm works](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). But even after I've added an `id` to each new message prior to being inserted into the array, it has that "lag" you're referring to. On closer inspection of that behaviour, it only occurs when you hit submit while also typing another character into the box. So that means both the `submit` and `(text) => setText(text)` were called simultaneously. I tried to come up with a solution, but nothing yet.

Comment: @98sean98 yes exactly you are right. I am "glad" you also have that issue. Is it a bug of react native? Since my code is really simple and I still have that issue.... Thanks for finding a solution too. :)

Comment: @Luka it is also in production mode.

Comment: I am still having that issue. it seems the more content but also the more child components and styles etc. are added, the more dramatic the issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the above idea, I use debounce for the setMessages. It prevent the value of TextInput not being cleared

Answer (score 0):

Since `submit` and `onChangeText` callbacks are fired simultaneously when a keyboard stroke and clicking the "submit" button happen together, I have debounced the `submit` callback to run with a 100ms delay.

See [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@98sean98/textinputlag).

The [use-debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce) library provides an elegant solution to handle user input events like these.

I have also removed the need for a `ref` by making `TextInput` controlled through passing `value={text}` prop.

As to why the `TextInput` does not `clear()` while `addMessage()` is successfully called (without the debouncing), I do not have an explanation at the moment. Would love to know if anyone could point out though.

## Fails to solve issue

After a couple more tests on my physical device, I'm occasionally observing the unwanted behaviour.

Comment: unfortunately the issue still exists, I just tried your snack on my device and it's the same, when spamming typing and submitting at the same time. I think the approach should be to look why it is only happening with large content. if there isn't much content on the screen it works fine.

Comment: Hmm... I tested on my iPhone SE 2 running the expo client. Did the simultaneity test, it seems ok. The character appears in the text input, then the text string is submitted.

Comment: On my iPhone XS the issue is still there... furthermore, based on the delay you added, you have now a little delay when submitting the text so it gets displayed, which is also not something I would want, since I want it to be fast.

Comment: Perhaps minimising the delay to < 10ms (human reaction is generally within the 100-200ms range, so anything less than 50ms should be barely noticeable) is the only way around this. My observation of Whatsapp, doing the same thing, has that bit of delay as well. Not sure if this delay is the same as what I suggested here, but I don't think users would care as long as its "not very noticeable".

Comment: Even though the issue is slightly better the app now feels generally less smooth. And the issue is still there (10ms delay): https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-1d19cf2325fe.gif

Comment: @André I stumbled onto [setNativeProps to clear text input value](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#setnativeprops-to-clear-textinput-value) by accident which might help.